# How to navigate to other page using function in angular without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am developing a web application where i want to navigate to other page on click of a button (navigateButton) without reloading or refreshing. I am using button (navigateButton) for all the rows in the datatable using jquery.
On click of button I want to navigate to other page without reload or refreshing.

I used  tag also, but I didn't get the solution.

My code till now:

```
$.ajax({
    url: API_url,
    type: "POST",
    data: { id: "31", version: "1"},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
        scriptTag.append("var optionTable = " + response.data + ";");
        document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
        var optionData = optionTable.Strikes;
        var content = '<table class="table table-bordered table-white">'
        content += '<thead class="thead-info"><tr class="callsBorder"><th class="callsDetails" colspan="6">CALLS</th><th class="">Action</th></tr></thead>'
        for (var i = 0; i < optionData.length; i++) {
            content += '<tr class="optionDataDet"><td><div>' + optionData[i].CALLS + '</div></td><button type="submit" onclick="navigateToOtherPage()" >Details</button></td></tr>';
        }
        content += '</table>'
        $('#div1').append(content);
    }
});

function navigateToOtherPage(event){
    window.location.href="/secondPage";
}
```

Comment: You can use the routerService provided by Angular

Answer (score 0):

In Angular would be something like this:

// 1. Import the Router Service provided by Angular.

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
```

// 2. Create an instance in your constructor.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

// 3. Use the router to navigate from your function.

```
function navigateToOtherPage(event) {
  this.router.navigate(["/secondPage"]);
}
```